# How to renumber the cases?

Tags: miktex

```
What is the procedure to renumbering the case inside a theorem?
```

I am discussing different cases for each theorem in my article. So I need to renumbering my cases. But it coming runningly. That is suppose first theorem consists two cases namely case 1 and case 2, in the second theorem if i start a case it is naming as case 3... How can i rectify this...[image]

Here i am including the codes i am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{lgrind,latexcad}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,thesisb1,fancyhdr,mathrsfs, indentfirst,dsfont}
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{.bmp}{bmp}{.bb}{}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
 \oddsidemargin .4in
 \evensidemargin .4in
 \topmargin 5pt      %    Nominal distance from top of page to top of
             %    box containing running head.
 %\headheight 6pt     %    Height of box containing running head.
 %\headsep 20pt
 \footskip 30pt
 \textheight 8.5in
 \textwidth 6in
 \parskip 0in
\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
           {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
                           {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \newtheoremstyle{label}% name
  {3pt}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {3pt}%      Space below
  {\upshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
 {}% Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{label}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{acknowledgement*}{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{step}{Step}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem*{claim*}{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{exercise*}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{summary}{Summary}[chapter]
\newtheoremstyle{label}% name
  {3pt}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {3pt}%      Space below
  {\upshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
 {}% Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{label}
\newtheorem*{step*}{Step}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheoremstyle{citing}% name
  {3pt}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {3pt}%      Space below
  {\upshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\normalfont}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
        %       \newline = linebreak
 {\thmnote{#3}}% Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{citing}
\newtheorem*{thmcite}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lmcite}{Lemma}
\newtheoremstyle{break1}% name
  {9pt}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {9pt}%      Space below
  {\upshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries \itshape}% Thm head font
  {}  %        Punctuation after thm head
  {.5em }% Space after thm head:
  {}%         Thm head spec
  \theoremstyle{break1}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}

%\newtheorem{example1}{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheoremstyle{label1}% name
  {2pt}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {2pt}%      Space below
  {\upshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\normalfont \itshape}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {.5em}%     Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
 {}% Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{label1}
\newtheorem{result}{Result}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{remark*}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note*}{Note}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}



%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
   {\markboth{{\, #1}}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
   \markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

%\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{n}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
\newcommand{\helv}{%
   \fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{m}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\lhead[\helv \thepage \hfill  \helv \nouppercase{\leftmark}] {}

\rhead[]{{\helv \nouppercase{\rightmark}} \hfill \helv
\thepage}\cfoot{}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\bc {\begin{center}}
 \def\ec {\end{center}}

% \lhead{\let\uppercase\relax\rightmark}
%\rhead{\let\uppercase\relax\leftmark}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
 \numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
 \numberwithin{table}{chapter}
 \newcommand{\ntt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}
%    command name
\newcommand{\cn}[1]{{\protect\ntt\bslash#1}}
\hfuzz1pc % Don't bother to report overfull boxes if overage is < 1pc

\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\S\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\lemref}[1]{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
%\newcommand{\bysame}{\mbox{\rule{3em}{.4pt}}\,}
\newcommand{\sqt}[1]{\sqrt{\smash[b] {#1}}}

%    \interval is used to provide better spacing after a [ that
%    is used as a closing delimiter.
\newcommand{\interval}[1]{\mathinner{#1}}

%    Notation for an expression evaluated at a particular condition. The
%    optional argument can be used to override automatic sizing of the
%    right vert bar, e.g. \eval[\biggr]{...}_{...}
\newcommand{\eval}[2][\right]{\relax
  \ifx#1\right\relax \left.\fi#2#1\rvert}

%    Enclose the argument in vert-bar delimiters:
\newcommand{\envert}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\let\abs=\envert

%    Enclose the argument in double-vert-bar delimiters:
\newcommand{\enVert}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\let\norm=\enVert
\newcommand{\pad}[2]{\frac{\der #1}{\der #2}}
\newcommand{\gol}{\mbox{$\,${\rm Log}$\,$}}
\newcommand{\Log}{\ln}
\newcommand{\ov}[1]{\overline{\smash[b] {#1}}}
\newcommand{\Ndash}{\nobreakdash--}
\newcommand{\BC}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\BN}{{\mathbb N}}
\newcommand{\BZ}{{\mathbb Z}}
\newcommand{\BR}{{\mathbb R}}
\newcommand{\IC}{{\mathds{C}}}
\newcommand{\IN}{{\mathds{N}}}
\newcommand{\IR}{{\mathds{R}}}
\newcommand{\IE}{{\mathbf{E}}}
\newcommand{\IF}{{\mathbf{F}}}
\newcommand{\minus}{ $ \nobreakdash --- $}
\newcommand{\division}{$\nobreakdash * $}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fixed Points in Transformational Geometry}
\begin{theorem}
 this is an example theorem..
\end{theorem}
\begin{case}
 this is case 1
\end{case}

\begin{case}
 this is case 2
\end{case}

\begin{theorem}
 i am starting second theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{case}
 this must give me case 1. But it is giving me case 3
\end{case}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  Furthermore, the solutions may depend on the exact packages that you are using.

Comment: the file `thesisb1.sty` isn't on ctan, and since it contains important definitions, such as that for `\chapter`, this example can't be processed without it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines after of to define `case` and `theorem`.

```
 \numberwithin{case}{theorem}
 \renewcommand{\thecase}{\arabic{case}}
```

Comment: it s giving me case 1.1 and all .. but i want case 1@skpblack

Comment: Your code is not compilable. You must add `thesisb1.sty` because this package is not standard. I assumed that your document is a `book` instead of an `article` (an `article` has not *chapters*) and i omitted  the `thesisb1` package. Please provide a *MWE* compilable to attempt help.

Comment: MWE???@skpblack

Comment: [What's a MWE?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) Please read